# Comparing Index Element of an Array

Tags: javascript, html

I need to compare the elements of two arrays to know if the first index is greater than the other one and vice versa but my if statement is not working.

```js
function winround(arr, arr2) {

    var set = Array.from(new Set(arr))
    var set2 = Array.from(new Set(arr2))
    var uniqueItems = set.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a
    });
    var uniqueItems2 = set2.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a
    });
    for (var i in uniqueItems)
        if (uniqueItems[0] > uniqueItems2[0])
            return "true";
        else {
            for (var i in uniqueItems2)
                if (uniqueItems[0] < uniqueItems2[0])
                    return "false";
        }
}
winround([2, 1, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1], [8, 6, 7]);
```

Comment: Please explain "not working". What exactly is this algorithm supposed to do? "know if the first index is greater than the other one" meaning `arr[0] > arr2[0]`?

Comment: winround([2, 5, 2, 6,9], [3, 7,, 3, 1, 2])  should return true since the first two higher digits in arr1 is greater than the first two higher digits in arr2. and vice versal

Comment: You need to better describe what the code needs to do. In the snippet you just compare the first indices of the arrays but _inside_ a loop. In the description you only mention the"first index". In the comment you mention "two" elements. We'll need you to re-express your problem to understand and help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `for(var i in uniqueItems)` . The purpose of the for-in statement is to enumerate over object properties.

Instead of this use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < uniqueItems.length; i++) {
  /* your code here */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside for loop of else part, you are always comparing the 1st element of 1st array with 1st element of 2nd array.

i.e., uniqueItems[0] <  **uniqueItems2[0]**

It should be: uniqueItems[0] <  **uniqueItems2[i]**

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you the answer in a much simpler way:

```js
function winround(arr, arr2) {
  return Math.max(...arr)>Math.max(...arr2);
}
console.log(winround([2,1,5,4,4,3,2,1], [8,6,7]));
```